# how do i write if..else statement using xpath

Tags: selenium

How do i write if--else statement using xpath.

`//div[@class='slick-viewport']/div/div`   --It gives me 5 following div tags.

```
<div class="custom-tooltip slick-cell l1 r1" xpath="1">
    <svg width="100%" height="25" version="1.1" id="SVG_b244db8a-9345-4d57-a865-115c447e4b33" data-ispopupdisplayallowed="true" data-measureid="484" data-is-pcp-user="false" data-is-po-user="true" onclick="openEngagementWithEcosystemSummary('SVG_b244db8a-9345-4d57-a865-115c447e4b33')" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
    <g></g>
    <text x="10" y="17" fill="black" style="font-weight: bolder; font-size: 12px;" id="PopUp_b244db8a-9345-4d57-a865-115c447e4b33"></text>
    </svg>
</div>
<div class="custom-tooltip slick-cell l1 r1" xpath="2">
    <svg width="100%" height="25" version="1.1" id="SVG_2264e127-682c-426f-a9fe-b3963363f9b3" data-ispopupdisplayallowed="true" data-measureid="486" data-is-pcp-user="false" data-is-po-user="true" onclick="openEPSDTCompletionRateSummary('SVG_2264e127-682c-426f-a9fe-b3963363f9b3')" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
    <g></g>
    <text x="10" y="17" fill="black" style="font-weight: bolder; font-size: 12px;" id="PopUp_f32ad3d5-e795-4752-9df4-814f99d265b7">
    51% </text>
    </svg>
</div>
<div class="custom-tooltip slick-cell l1 r1" xpath="2">
    <svg width="100%" height="25" version="1.1" id="SVG_2264e127-682c-426f-a9fe-b3963363f9b3" data-ispopupdisplayallowed="true" data-measureid="486" data-is-pcp-user="false" data-is-po-user="true" onclick="openEPSDTCompletionRateSummary('SVG_2264e127-682c-426f-a9fe-b3963363f9b3')" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
    <g></g>
    <text x="10" y="17" fill="black" style="font-weight: bolder; font-size: 12px;" id="PopUp_f32ad3d5-e795-4752-9df4-814f99d265b7">
    31% </text>
    </svg>
</div>
    <div class="custom-tooltip slick-cell l1 r1" xpath="3">
    <svg width="100%" height="25" version="1.1" id="SVG_cd847418-1c52-465a-a473-1e3ae2a0b979" data-ispopupdisplayallowed="false" data-measureid="485" data-is-pcp-user="false" data-is-po-user="true" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
    <g></g>
    <text x="10" y="17" fill="black" style="font-weight: bolder; font-size: 12px;" id="PopUp_cd847418-1c52-465a-a473-1e3ae2a0b979">
    Available 
    </text>
    </svg>
</div>
    <div class="custom-tooltip slick-cell l1 r1" xpath="4">
    <svg width="100%" height="25" version="1.1" id="SVG_856b33a6-b361-4020-a01c-fbccb9d171de" data-ispopupdisplayallowed="false" data-measureid="500" data-is-pcp-user="false" data-is-po-user="true" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
    <text x="10" y="17" fill="black" style="font-weight: bolder; font-size: 12px;" id="PopUp_856b33a6-b361-4020-a01c-fbccb9d171de">
    Available 
    </text>
    </svg>
</div>
```

In Short,

```
//div[@class='@class='slick-viewport'']//div[2]//*[name()='svg' and @data-ispopupdisplayallowed='true']
```

--Giving 3 elements(rows)

Second  and third row contains the tag text which contains value/string "51%" and 31% while first row does not contain any value for text tag..

```
//div[@class='@class='slick-viewport']//div[2]//*[name()='svg' and @data-ispopupdisplayallowed='false'] ---Giving 2 elements(rows)
```

My for loop will execute 5 times(`totalNoOfDivs.size()`)

Need a help to write it down if...else statement for above 3 conditions and will be part of for loop.

1st condition needed for ----Not contain any text the text tag.`(@data-ispopupdisplayallowed='true')`

2nd condition needed for -----contain the text such as 51%, 31% `(@data-ispopupdisplayallowed='true')`

3rd condition needed for -- Just to fetch the text "Available"`(@data-ispopupdisplayallowed='false')`

In short all 3 conditions perform different operations after clicking on row so need to put in for with if...else statement.
Any help will be appreciated.....

Comment: Will this Strings will help to put condition.                                                                                  String xpathpopUp="//div[@class='slick-viewport']//div[2]//*[name()='svg' and @data-ispopupdisplayallowed='true']";                                                                                                                        String xpathgetText= "//div[@class='slick-viewport']//div[2]//*[name()='svg' and @data-ispopupdisplayallowed='false']";

Comment: Question is too broad. 1) Not contain any text the text tag.(@data-ispopupdisplayallowed='true') 2) contain the text such as 51%, 31% (@data-ispopupdisplayallowed='true') and 3) fetch the text "Available". Can you reduce the scope of the question please?

Comment: I do have 3 xpaths for my all rows. Xpath(1) -//div[@class='slick-viewport']//div[2]//*[name()='svg' and @data-ispopupdisplayallowed='true'] --This path gives me popup having 1 column which wanted to display on console.  Xpath(2) --  //div[@class='slick-viewport']//div[2]//*[name()='svg' and @data-ispopupdisplayallowed='true']//*[name()='text']  gives me popup with 5 columns. Xpath(3)- //div[@class='slick-viewport']//div[2]//*[name()='svg' and @data-ispopupdisplayallowed='false']//*[name()='text'] No popup just text "Not Available". Wanted to put all 3 paths with if else in a for loop.

Comment: I tried following but printing the 5 values from first popup only.for(int i=0; i<NoOfDivs; i++)  //Main loop
{   if(_xpath.contains("[name()='svg']"))
 {
 clickOnPCPEnMeasureListOneAfterOther.get(i).click(); 
 for(int j=0;j<5;j++)
  { System.out.println(totalNoOfProvider.get(j).getText()); }
  Actions act = new Actions(driver);
  act.moveToElement(closePopup).click().build().perform(); }
else if (xpathgetText1.contains("data-ispopupdisplayallowed='false']//*[name()='text']"))
{ System.out.println(textAvailable.getText());    }
 else  
System.out.println("Not available");

Comment: Its click on first row again, popup get open and then throwing an error "org.openqa.selenium.StaleElementReferenceException: stale element reference: element is not attached to the page document".

Answer (score 0):

You could find all the elements and them step through them using a for loop:

```
var elements = driver.FindElements(By.Xpath("//div[@class='slick-viewport']/div/div"));

for (int i = 0; i < elements.Count; i++)
{
     <if then logic here>
}
```